# What are efficient ways to pass events between a library and the GUI?

Tags: c, events, rust

I'm writing a library that does some IO asynchronously. Different types of GUIs will use this library to create the same application but for different platforms. The library generates events that the GUI wants to use. The library is written in Rust, but I envision it having a C interface where the GUI will provide some memory and call initialization functions.

- I could poll the library often. (not efficient)
- I could have a blocking function that returns once an event occurs. (inconvenient, especially when I want to stop the application)

Comment: Many GUIs are written as event-handling loops - so they could register event handlers that the library could call when an event occurs.  And your library would just generate the events, queue them up, and pass them up to the registered handlers.

Comment: "I could have a blocking function that returns once an event occurs. (inconvenient, especially when I want to stop the application)" - so *why* would you want to stop the application if not due to an external event occurring?

Comment: E.g. if the user click an exit button in the GUI. But I guess it's not that much of an inconvenience, as I could have a function that tells the library to shutdown, releasing the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the library with a `post_event` function. Whenever an event occurrs that the library wants to post to the GUI, it calls this function.

The post function could be blocking (it returns once the event has been handled) or non-blocking (it just posts the event in the GUI's message loop and returns immediately). Or it could be blocking for some events and not for others.

As an example:

User calls Library initialization:

```
int post_event(int eventID, long prm1, long prm2); // prototype
myLibInit(post_event);                            // call
```

Inside library initialization:

```
static int (*libPostEvent)(int eventID, long prm1, long prm2); // global variable with pointer to user's post function
void myLibInit( int(*f)(int,long,long)) {
    libPostEvent= f;
}
```

Event occurrs in library

```
    ...
    switch (libPostEvent(eventID, prm1, prm2)) {
    case ... // handle result
    }
```

Inside GUI:

```
int post_event(int eventID, long prm1, long prm2)
{
    switch (eventID) {
    case EVENT1: putmsgqueu(EVENT1, prm1); return 1; // non-blocking
    case EVENT2: return(do_something());             // blocking
    }
    return 0; // not handled
}
```